# Understanding a javascript code fragment

Tags: javascript

Good morning!

I am hoping that someone on this platform can explain the lin-by-line working of following JS

```
<script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    (function(w, a, b, d, s) {
        w[a] = w[a] || {};
        w[a][b] = w[a][b] || {
            q: [],
            track: function(r, e, t) {
                this.q.push({
                    r: r,
                    e: e,
                    t: t || +new Date
                });
            }
        };
        var e = d.createElement(s);
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        e.async = 1;
        e.src = '//flintnet.actonservice.com/cdnr/94/acton/bn/tracker/17118';
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(e, f);
    })(window, 'ActOn', 'Beacon', document, 'script');
    ActOn.Beacon.track(); /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I have a good working knowledge of JS but am not able to fully understand this! Thank you!

Comment: Which line is blur for you?

Comment: The bulk of it is just loading a script async and setting up a specified global namespace  dummy object/methods acting as a placeholder and queue in case you have other stuff that calls it before the script fully loads. It's a pretty common setup for tracking scripts, which is what this basically looks like. you can see a similar setup with google universal analytics or a lot of other remarketing tags

Comment: @slick Everthing above var statement. What exactly does each line do? Whats the purpose?

Answer (score 5):

It's essentially this

```
window.ActOn = window.Acton || {}; // create ActOn global if it doesn't exist
window.Acton.Beacon = window.Acton.Beacon || { // create Beacon object on ActOn if it doesn't exist
    q: [], // an empty array
    track: function(r, e, t) { // function to push {r: arg1, e: arg2, t: arg3 || now} onto q
        this.q.push({
            r: r,
            e: e,
            t: t || +new Date
        });
    }
};
var e = document.createElement('script'); // create a script element
var f = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; // find the first script in the document
e.async = 1; // set async = "1" on the new script element
e.src = '//flintnet.actonservice.com/cdnr/94/acton/bn/tracker/17118'; // set the source of the script element
f.parentNode.insertBefore(e, f); // insert the script as the top most script on the page - this will fail on a page with no scripts

ActOn.Beacon.track(); // add a "track" to beacon.q = { r: undefined, e: undefined, t: now }
```

Comment: What is CDATA. Why does track call without params.

Comment: Nice job noting the failure case :)

Comment: actually, good job. he asked lin-by-line. you just write that it is deprecated(it is for XHTML. you already writed to comment.+1). I didn't see your edited answer.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev - there's been no edit on the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the comments. I really appreciate it! Why can't they just use a script to simply call the desired tracking function ActOn.Beacon.track()? Won't that be straight forward and easily understandable?

Comment: i saw your answer in my phone  at the street. maybe. i didn't see you comments(`//`) line by line. Sorry

Comment: @AmanKejriwal. That(ActOn.Beacon.track() ) is avoided conflicts with many scripts in varios projects, I think.

Comment: Also, they use letters( for variables) for decreasing  capacity

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    // see "Interface CDATASection" at http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-667469212
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    // `window, 'ActOn', 'Beacon', document, 'script'`
    (function(w, a, b, d, s) {
        w[a] = w[a] || {}; // `window['ActOn'] = window['ActOn'] || {}`
        w[a][b] = w[a][b] || { // `window['ActOn']['Beacon'] = {q:[],..}`
            q: [], // empty array
            // do stuff
            track: function(r, e, t) { // `r, e, t` ?
                this.q.push({
                    r: r,
                    e: e,
                    t: t || +new Date
                });
            }
        };
        var e = d.createElement(s); // create `script` element
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; // first `script` element in document
        e.async = 1; // set `async`: `true`
        // set `e` `src` , load created `script` element
        e.src = '//flintnet.actonservice.com/cdnr/94/acton/bn/tracker/17118';
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(e, f); // insert `e`: `script` before first `script` element
    })(window, 'ActOn', 'Beacon', document, 'script'); // variables
    // call `ActOn.Beacon.track` , defined as property of `window` above
    ActOn.Beacon.track(); /*]]>*/
</script>
```